# assigning columns using ifelse and within

Tags: r, if-statement

Why does the function ifelse and within cannot work together? As an example to illustrate the problem, I have the following code. What I wanted is to create two columns (Petal.Dim1 and Petal.Dim2 which are just Petal.Width and Petal.Length) but switches whenever Sepal.Length is greater than 5.

```
data(iris)
within(iris, ifelse(Sepal.Length>5,{
                Petal.Dim1 <-Petal.Width
                Petal.Dim2 <-Petal.Length
            }, {
                Petal.Dim1<-Petal.Length
                Petal.Dim2<-Petal.Width}))
```

Comment: You're misreading the help file (`?iflese`). `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as the test. That is, it doesn't do the operation, it returns the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say what is wrong with your code, but I can suggest to use `transform`:

```
data(iris)
dat <- transform(iris, 
    Petal.Dim1=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5, Petal.Width, Petal.Length),
    Petal.Dim2=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
)
str(dat)
```

EDIT:
A more robust way would be (in my opinion) to store the indizes and avoid `within` or `transform`:

```
idx <- iris[,"Sepal.Length"] > 5
dat <- iris
dat[idx, "Dim1"] <- Petal.Width
dat[idx, "Dim2"] <- Petal.Length
dat[!idx, "Dim1"] <- Petal.Length
dat[!idx, "Dim2"] <- Petal.Width
```

Maybe it is even faster, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: cool, this works but how do I put Petal.Dim1 and Petal.Dim2 within 1 ifelse? I have to scale this with multiple columns on a larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about using non-standard evaluation. `within` is just a wrapper around `eval`, so both of those blocks get executed since it doesn't know about the behavior of `ifelse`. You want something like:

```
dat <- within(iris, {
  Petal.Dim1 <- ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Width, Petal.Length)
  Petal.Dim2 <- ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
})
```